Finding the sum of a series using the binomial theorem
If $(1+x+x^2)^n = a_{0} + a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2 + ... + a_{2n}x^{2n}$, prove that $a_{0}^2-a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+...+(-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}^2= \frac{1}{2}a_{n}(1-(-1)^na_{n})$.
I was able to find the value of $a_{0}^2-a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2-...+a_{2n}^2$ ($=a_{n}$) by substituting $x=\frac{-1}{x}$ in the first expression, the sum turns out to be the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^4)$, which is $a_n$. Can that be used here?

Yes that observation can be used, and it is argubaly the crux. I'd encourage you to try the problem from here, else look at the solution in the linked problem.

@CalvinLin can I get the proof for a palindrome raised to some power also being a palindrome?
